# Is 'not (a == b)' equal to 'a != b' in Python?

Tags: python

I think in Python `==` should check for equality, and `is` for identity.

From a logical point of view, I think `not (a == b)` should be equal to `a != b`. Do I overlook something?

Two things came to my mind: (1) Classes which implement `__ne__` and `__eq__` in a bad way (2) Something with floats / `float('nan')`. But I couldn't find any examples where the two expressions would not be equivalent. Their byte code isn't:

```
>>> def a(compare):
...     return not compare == "in"


>>> def b(compare):
...     return compare != "in"

>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (compare)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('in')
              4 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              6 UNARY_NOT
              8 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(b)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (compare)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('in')
              4 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Related to [What is the dunder method for unary 'not' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64010574/562769)

Comment: I mean yes, but the latter is preffered